# Detect event (like click) on dynamic content

Tags: jquery, html

How to detect which dynamic button is clicked?
***Note:*** The `#dCalc` Element is added dynamically...

```html
<!-- STATIC -->
<div id="dBlock">

  <!-- ADDED DYNAMICALLY -->
  <div id="dCalc">
    <input id="firstNumber" type="text" maxlength="3" />
    <input id="secondNumber" type="text" maxlength="3" />
    <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Add" />
    <input id="btn2" type="button" value="Subtract" />
    <input id="btn3" type="button" value="Multiply" />
    <input id="btn4" type="button" value="Divide" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
$("input").click(function(e){
    var idClicked = e.target.id;
});
```

Comment: `Event.target` will only work in this specific case (`<input>` with no children) - Always use `Event.currentTarget` instead of `Event.target` - no matter what (or unless you really know what you're doing). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75204988/383904) for proper handling of **delegated events**

Answer (score 6):

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="button"]').click(function() { alert('You clicked button with ID:' + this.id); });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the block is added dynamically you could try:

```
jQuery( document).delegate( "#dCalc input[type='button']", "click",
    function(e){
    var inputId = this.id;
    console.log( inputId );
    }
);
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/yDNWc/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery can be bound to an individual input/button, or to all of the buttons in your form. Once a button is clicked, it will return the object of that button clicked. From there you can check attributes such as value...

```
$('#dCalc input[type="button"]').click(function(e) {
    // 'this' Returns the button clicked:
    // <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Add">
    // You can bling this to get the jQuery object of the button clicked
    // e.g.: $(this).attr('id'); to get the ID: #btn1
    console.log(this);

    // Returns the click event object of the button clicked.
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Technically, `e` represent the click event object, not the button object.

Comment: @mblase75, actually the click event object is `e.originalEvent`, `e` is jQuery generated custom object that has "cross browserized" properties for convenience, and doesn't include some things that are in the `e.originalEvent` :P

Comment: @Esailija Well, clearly I've just been out-technicallyed. Thanks for the details

Answer (score 0):

## Detect event on dynamically created elements

Two examples, jQuery and *vanilla* **JavaScript** ahead:

#### jQuery

Use the [.on() method with delegated events](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), which follows this syntax:

```js
$("staticParentSelector").on("eventName", "dynamicChildSelector", handlerFn);
```

Example:

```js
// Assign event listeners to dynamic child elements
// Will work for either existent elements or inserted in the future

$("#dBlock").on("click", '[type="button"]', (evt) => {
  
  const staticParent = evt.delegateTarget; // This is #dBlock
  const dynamicChild = evt.currentTarget;  // This is the dynamic child
  
  console.log(`Static Parent ID is: ${staticParent.id}`)
  console.log(`Dynamic child ID is: ${dynamicChild.id}`)
  
});
```

```html
<!-- STATIC -->
<div id="dBlock">

  <!-- ADDED DYNAMICALLY -->
  <div id="dCalc">
    <button type="button" id="btn1">Add</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn2">Subtract</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn3">Multiply</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn4">Divide</button>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### JavaScript

The same in *vanilla* JavaScript can be achieved like the following, with the difference in that JS has no notion of *delegateTarget* (which is a jQuery property on their proprietary Event object) therefore the slight modification:

```js
// Assign event listeners to dynamic child elements
// Will work for either existent elements or inserted in the future

document.querySelector("#dBlock").addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  
  const staticParent = evt.currentTarget; // This is #dBlock
  const dynamicChild = evt.target.closest('[type="button"]');  // This is the dynamic child
  
  if (!dynamicChild) return; // Do nothing (no designated dynamic child is clicked)
  
  console.log(`Static Parent ID is: ${staticParent.id}`)
  console.log(`Dynamic child ID is: ${dynamicChild.id}`)
  
});
```

```html
<!-- STATIC -->
<div id="dBlock">

  <!-- ADDED DYNAMICALLY -->
  <div id="dCalc">
    <button type="button" id="btn1">Add</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn2">Subtract</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn3">Multiply</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn4">Divide</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

as you can see neither of the above implementations stick solely on the `Event.target` Element *per-se*, for the reason that if we had i.e. an icon inside the buttons (like: `<button id="add" type="button">Add <i class="icon-plus"></i></button>`) and if a click landed on the icon directly, the `Event.target` would end up being the icon, not the Button Element - and we might miss to retrieve the needed data, like the specific button ID etc, resulting in a broken app logic.