# How to get which link has been clicked in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

Good day...

I have multiple links as below:

```
<li><a href="#" id="mmSaveForm" class="itemDisabled noTxtSelect1">Save</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="mmSaveAs" class="itemDisabled noTxtSelect1">Save As</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="mmSaveExit" class="itemDisabled noTxtSelect1">Save And Exit</a></li>
```

I wanna know which link has been clicked
I tried something like this:

```
if ($("#mmSaveForm").click() == "true") {
    //do something
}
else if ($("mmSaveAs").click() == "true") {
    //Do something
}
else if ($("#mmSaveExit").click() == "true") {
    //Do something
}
```

I tried these links, questions & answers but they are not helping:

[How can I get the button that caused the submit from the form submit event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066162/how-can-i-get-the-button-that-caused-the-submit-from-the-form-submit-event)

[jQuery: how to get which button was clicked upon form submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721724/jquery-how-to-get-which-button-was-clicked-upon-form-submission)

[how to detect which button is clicked using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919328/how-to-detect-which-button-is-clicked-using-jquery)

[jQuery - how to determine which link was clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862764/jquery-how-to-determine-which-link-was-clicked)

I've been trying this the whole night, please help...
Thank you in advanced...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you target the class instead, grab the `id` and then use a switch statement.

```
$('.itemDisabled').on('click', function () {
  var id = this.id;
  switch(id) {
    case 'mmSaveForm':
      // code
      break;
    case 'mmSaveAs':
      // code
      break;
    case 'mmSaveExit':
      // code
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: I prefer this method, as I find a lot of case statements are easier to read than a bunch of `if()`'s.

Comment: Me too. The other better way, if you have loads of cases, is to use an object to store your methods and just reference the keys as needed: e.g. `obj.mmSaveForm();`.

Comment: This method is faster due to the use of 'this' from vanilla JS.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`.is(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/is/#is-selector) to identify the element which has been clicked,

```
$('a.noTxtSelect1').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();  
   if($(this).is("#mmSaveForm")){

   } else if($(this).is("#mmSaveAs")) {

   } else if($(this).is("#mmSaveExit")) {

   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your links have `id` attributes all starting with 'mm' you could use:

```
$('a[id^=mm]').on('click', function(){
   console.log(this.id); 
});
```

Or on one or more classes:

`$('a.itemDisabled').on('click', function(){`

-or-

`$('a.itemDisabled.noTxtSelect1').on('click', function(){`

In the click event, you can use switch to determine the link clicked, which you can fetch using `this` or `$(this)`

e.g.:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TbmU4/)

```
$('a[id^=mm]').on('click', function () {
    switch (this.id) {
        case "mmSaveForm":
            alert(this.id);
            break;
        case "mmSaveAs":
            alert(this.id);
            break;
        case "mmSaveExit":
            alert(this.id);
            break;

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use common class like a itemDisabled for click event and get id ,

```
$(".itemDisabled").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var id = this.id;
     if (id === "mmSaveForm") {

     } else if (id === "mmSaveExit") {

     } else {}

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[attr^="value"]` ["starts with"] selector:

```
$('[id^="mmSave"]').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var action = this.id;
  // do your business
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about this the wrong way. In your

```
$(document).ready(function() {})
```

you register for click events. So something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#mmSaveForm").click(function() {
        // handle the click
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try this

```
$(function(){
        $('.linkclass').click(function(){
           var link_text = $(this).text();
           alert('the clicked link text is '+ link_text);
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

No need jquery please look this code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html >
<html >
<head>
<script>
function clickbtn(t)
{
    alert(t.id);
    /*if(t.id==...) 
    {
        dosomething();
    }
    else
    {
        dootherthing();
    }
    */
}
</script>
</head>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" onclick="clickbtn(this)" id="mmSaveForm" class="itemDisabled noTxtSelect1">Save</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="clickbtn(this)" id="mmSaveAs" class="itemDisabled noTxtSelect1">Save As</a></li>
<li><a href="#"  onclick="clickbtn(this)" id="mmSaveExit" class="itemDisabled noTxtSelect1">Save And Exit</a></li>
</ul>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

It work ok .
Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

This is my html page (Django template):

```
<div class="col">
    {% for blog in blogs %}
    <div class="post">
        <h3><a href="{% url 'blog:detail' pk=blog.pk %}">{{ blog.title }}</a></h3>
        <div class="date">
            <p>Created: {{blog.date_created|date:'d M Y'}}</p>
        </div>
        <p>{{ blog.brief|safe }}</p>  

        <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'blog:edit' pk=blog.pk %}">Edit</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="publish" href="{{blog.pk}}">Publish</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="btn btn-danger" id="remove" href="{{blog.pk}}">Remove</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        <br>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

In my javascript file, this is what have and it works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

console.log("document is ready!!!")

$('#id_bloglist').on("click", 'a#publish,a#remove', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault()

    var pk = $(this).attr("href")

    if ($(this)[0].id == 'remove'){
        console.log("remove link clicked, calling deleteBlog with pk = " + pk)
    }
    else if ($(this)[0].id == 'publish'){
        console.log("publish link clicked, calling publishBlog with pk = " + pk)
    }

    return false;
});
```

});