# remove and add items in shopping cart

Tags: javascript, html

when I click the cross icon in shopping cart for first time it works well , but problem occurs when you want to add new items into shopping cart it is the time the cross icon doesn't work. as far as I know cross icon works exactly before you want to add new items
the html of cart:

shopping cart html part:

```
 <div class="cart-container col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <div class="content-container">
                <div class="img-container">
                    <div class="img-box"><img src="images/cart-item-1.png" class="cart-img"  alt=""></div>
                    <div class="price-box">
                        <h3>cart item 01</h3>
                        <p>$15.99/-</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="xmark"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

(add to cart button) html part:

```
  <div class="box">
                    <img src="images/menu-1.png" class="buy-coffee" alt="cappuccino">
                    <h3>tasty and healty</h3>
                    <div class="price">
                        $15.99
                        <span>$20.99</span>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button">add to cart</button>
                </div>
```

function which remove item from shopping cart:

```
const crossIcons = document.querySelectorAll('.fa-xmark');
     for(let crossIcon of crossIcons){
            crossIcon.addEventListener("click",function(event){
                this.closest('div.content-container').remove();
            })
```

function for adding new items to shopping cart:

```
let addTocarts = document.querySelectorAll('.box button');
 for (let addToCart of addTocarts) {
            addToCart.addEventListener("click", myfunc);
            function myfunc(event) {
                event.preventDefault()
                let boxImg
                let boxSelect = addToCart.closest('div.box');
                boxImg = boxSelect.children[0].getAttribute('src');
                let el = ` <div class="content-container">
                <div class="img-container">
                    <div class="img-box"><img src="${boxImg}" class="cart-img" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="price-box">
                        <h3>cart item 01</h3>
                        <p>$15.99/-</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="xmark"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark" ></i></div>
            </div>`;


                document.querySelector('.cart-container').innerHTML += el;
            }
        }
```

I just want to add and remove items for cart shop

Comment: There are so much bad coding in this. Please look up event delegation and have only ONE click function for all items

Comment: For example `document.querySelector('.cart-container').addEventListener('click', (e) => { const tgt = e.target; if (tgt.matches('.fa-xmark')) tgt.closest('div.content-container').remove(); });` - this code is all you need on the page to delete any cart item in a `div.content-container` now and after adding

Comment: Head to this answer for more details [Detect event (like click) on dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75204988/383904)

Comment: It works well I realy appreciate for your answer.